# SQL Server Memory Consumption

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL Server 2012 installed on a machine with 64 GB of RAM. Nothing except SQL Server is installed in this machine.

SQL Server occupies all physical memory and that results in time out exception in my web application.

When I restart the SQL Server, it gets down to 15 GB and then it increased gradually and after about two weeks of time, it reaches up to 50 GB which results into time out exception.

Can someone suggest solution for this, as it is not recommended to restart SQL Server after every two weeks of time ?

Thanks

Comment: That's **by design** - unless you specifically limit SQL Server, it will always use as much memory as it can get, to get the best performance possible. If nothing else is running on that machine - where's the problem??

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will continue caching query plans, tables etc. till it reaches maximum usable memory that OS provides OR till it reaches `MAX MEMORY` setting. So please check your MAX MEMORY setting and reduce it if needed. For reference please check [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

I am reproducing `Examples` given:

Example A

The following example sets the max server memory option to 4 GB:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Example B. Determining Current Memory Allocation

The following query returns information about currently allocated memory.

```
SELECT
(physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024) AS Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB,
(locked_page_allocations_kb/1024) AS Locked_pages_used_Sqlserver_MB,
(total_virtual_address_space_kb/1024) AS Total_VAS_in_MB,
process_physical_memory_low,
process_virtual_memory_low
FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory;
```

Secondly, are there any CLR components? These will use additional memory and may continue to hold.

Thirdly, check the client application that uses SQL server. There could be open connections holding data.

Answer (score 1):

you can configure the max memory by ui.

Go to SSMS -> select server name ->right click properies -> go to memory tab and in right side pane give the maximum size. By default it is unlimited, means if sql need memory and processor have memory, sqlserver consume the whole.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191144%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Still if you have trouble, then click the "Use AWE To allocate memory".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180797%28v=sql.105%29.aspx